# why set insert failed after overloading the comparing operator in C++?

Tags: c++, set, operator-overloading

```
class Comp1 {
public:
    bool operator() (const pair<int, int> a1, const pair<int, int>a2) const{
        if (a1.first < a2.first)
            return false;
        else if (a1.second > a2.second)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
};
set<pair<int, int>, Comp1> aset;
aset.insert(pair<int, int>(3, 4));
aset.insert(pair<int, int>(4, 1));
```

I have clearly defined the compare operator. But why the `aset.insert(pair<int, int>(4, 1));` is not sucessful?

Comment: You should only be checking a1.second if a1.first is equal to a2.first. in fact im not sure why you overloaded the operator because im fairly convinced std::pair's operators do that by default.

Comment: Your comparator says that `(3, 4)` and `(4, 1)` are equivalent; neither is less than the other. So the second `insert` does nothing since `std::set` already holds an equivalent key.

Comment: you are right. The insert will compare (a1, a2) and (a2, a1).